# Capture response sent to webhook rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, xml-parsing, webhooks

I'm working with my first webhook in my rails application.  My HookController is receiving the following response:

```
Started POST "/hooks/callback" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-18 14:10:13 -0500
Processing by HooksController#callback as HTML
Parameters: {"Status"=>"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<BackgroundReports userId=\"username\" ...
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

I'm trying parse the XML that is returned in the parameters and I'm getting stuck.

I have tried starting with the following in my controller raising :

```
webHook = JSON.parse(params[:status])
raise webHook.inspect
```

But it appears as if its not capturing the params.

How do I capture the params and parse the XML in my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to troubleshoot the problem myself.
I am using Devise for my User model.  That was driving the 401 Unauthorized error.  As a result I was not able to to pull and parse the params.

I found the answer in a similar question -> [Webhook returning 401 in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235958/webhook-returning-401-in-rails) on Stakoverflow.  Adding the following allowed Devise to authenticate the response.  I could parse the params from there:

```
skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token, :authenticate_user!
```